# Detect which GPO Setting are changing folder permissions

Tags: windows-7, permissions, group-policy

How can I figure out what part of GPO policy is causing folder permissions to be changed?

Office 365 can't register on some of our network computers because the "Network Service" account doesn't have access to the "c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\OfficeSoftwareProtectionPlatform" folder.  If we grant access to that folder, it disappears as soon as you do a GPUpdate.

I have read through the Effective GPO Policy a few times and I still haven't managed to find the entry that is making this change.  Is there an easier way to figure out what part of the GPO Policy is making this change?

I know I could just configure a higher priority policy to set permissions correctly, but I still would like to know what is making the change.

Comment: I presume you mean, specificaly`NetworkService`, and not some other manually created service account that might exist on your system?

Comment: I assume you also have the Office Administrative Templates installed?

Comment: Correct, the Network Service built-in account.

Comment: I am not sure honestly, but either way it almost certainly isn't the 2016 one.

Comment: You should verify which administrative template(s) you have installed and update your question.

Comment: In any event, you can use the group policy, `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\File System\` and add the service account (to do this across your domain use  the SID of the account)  [NetworkService Account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: That's is where it was, I used rsop.msc to see it.

Comment: You should submit an answer since it's not clear what you did to solve your problem, you should, be specific and provide details

Answer (score 1):

Using the Resultant Set of Policy snap-in (rsop.msc) on one of the computers I was having an issue on and looking at the policy path of `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\File System`, I was able to see what was causing the issue.